# Justify the small angle approximation for tangent

Tags: trigonometry

Assume that angle $x$ is small, using small angle approximation,

$\sin(x)=x$;

$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}$;

and $\tan(x)=x$.

I am able to justify the first two using Maclaurin's Theorem but not the last one. How do we justify the last one?

Comment: Hint : Taylor formula for tan(x)

Comment: We have a series expansion for $tan(x)$ also when $x$ is small , higher powers get neglected only first power will remain and hence it $x$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for small $x$, $\frac{1}{\cos{x}}\approx\frac{1}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}\approx 1+\frac{x^2}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple actually:

$$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\approx\frac x{1-\frac{x^2}2}=x\left(1+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}4+\dots\right)\approx x\big(1+\mathcal O(x^2)\big)$$

where we used known approximations and the geometric series.